# strange behaviour of the Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, compilation

I have some problems with Eclipse:

Sometimes I write the code and compile it and all works perfectly, after I begin to change my code and compile one more time, but Eclipse does nothing.
**Only after I delete the folder *Debug* it compiles the program**

My question is why? And how can I switch the behaviour to compile every time from the beginning.
For example:

```
if(x == 0)        # ... I compile, and it works...
# after I do one change to my code 
if(x==0 && y==0)  # ... Eclipse do nothing even if y is not declared
```

Comment: Is the menu item Project/Build Automatically turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about a CDT project (C/C++), not a JDT one (Java).

If so, not that if you delete the debug folder, you cannot run directly the application ([bug 296243](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=296243)).

Check if the 'Build (Build Incremental)' is disabled or not: [bug 198097](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=198097).

Comment: @VonC: I can't find Build Incremental properties, can You help please?

Comment: @rookie: well first, are you in a CDT (C/C++) project?

Comment: @VonC: yeap, it's ok, I've already found it, my build incremental is not disabled. So is it possible to fix this problem in Eclipse? I didn't understand it from your link, thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: @rookie: is there an "automatically build" option as well? Anyway, try a full refresh from your project instead of deleting the debug folder and see if it helps for the second build.

Comment: @VonC: doesn't help, the same problem:(, there is no automatically build option, do I need it? anyway I checked with this option, the same...

Comment: @rookie: Can you import your project (.classpath and .project) into a new workspace in a fresh Eclipse installation to see if that behaviour persists?

Comment: @rookie: what version of JDK, Eclipse and CDT are you using by the way?

Comment: @rookie: it would be interesting to get the latest 3.6.1 (and even a 3.7M3) and the latest CDT plugin, with the latest JDK6u22 to launch said Eclipse, and an eclipse.ini adapted ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659 ) and see if the problem persists then.